# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->autoIncrement();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('position_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('taskmaster');
            $table->Integer('task_id');
            $table->string('title',150);
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('finished_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('position_id')->references('id')->on('positions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('taskmaster')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('firmas')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('jobs');
    }
```

I have a problem on laravel. When I add the first two foreign keys, it does not give a problem, but when I add the foreign key of the 'company' table at the bottom, it gives an error. The error is as follows:

```
 General error: 1005 Can't create table `advertisement`.`jobs` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `jobs` add constraint `jobs_task_id_foreign` foreign key (`task_id`) references `firmas` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

Answer (score 3):

There should be the same datatype of the column in firmas table id is of type integer if not then change the code

$table->Integer('task id'); to below code.

```
$table-›unsignedBigInteger('task id');
```

Comment: I still have problem because i changed as your code but problem is not solve

Comment: getting same error, check the data type of ‘id’ in the ‘firmas’ table then tell me

Comment: ` Schema::create('firmas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->autoIncrement();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('jobs_id');
            $table->string('firma_name')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('jobs_id')->references('id')->on('jobs')->onDelete('cascade');
        });  `

Comment: why you have used auto increment in front of id laravel by default make it auto increment and data type unsigned big integer. Remove the auto increment and run migration again then the above code will work.

Comment: I tried what you said but still the same error. I removed the id auto-increment in the company, I made it bigint, it gives the same error again

Comment: company? In ‘firmas’ table you have to add id like this `$table->id();` if that not work. we can connect through anydesk

Comment: it did not solve this problem

Comment: you can take reference from here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key and foreign key type must remain same. For laravel it is by default UnsignedBigInteger. So check and try each and every foreign and primary key type which must be UNSIGNED BIG INT.

Or you can try.

```
$table->foreignId('position_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

It simply creates the position_id column contrained with positions table.

Read Here. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId

Answer (score 0):

add unsigned() method like this..

```
 //make id on firmas 
    $table->id()
   //and on jobs like this
        $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('firmas')->onDelete('cascade');
    //or
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('firmas');
```

try this maybe it will help you